# I need to fadein fadeout 3 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new do Jquery and I'm trying to fadein and fadeout 3 divs.
It need's to stay looped and I can't get it work.

This is my html markup:

```
<div id="section1"></div>
<div id="section2"></div>
<div id="section3"></div>
```

Any help?

Comment: Please post the jQuery code that you've already tried, and which you can't get to work.

Comment: `$('#section1,#section2,#section3').fadeIn()` isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a common class to all divs and wrap them in a div.

Try:

```
var len = $("#container").find(".section").length;
setInterval(function(){
    var current = $(".section:visible");
    var active = $(current).index();
    var next;
    if(active == len-1){
        next = 0;
    }
    else{
        next = active+1;
    }
    $(current).hide();
    $("#container .section:eq("+next+")").fadeIn();
},1000);
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/BKdGF/3)

Comment: there's one problem...when page loads, the first div stays "hide" and after 1 sec the first one appears and the slide starts...I guess that's because it's waiting for 1 sec to change the display:none of the first div...how can I fix it?!

Comment: @user1541940 probably waiting for DOM ready. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/BKdGF/2/) given timeout of 10 seconds. Edited answer.

Comment: Yes, it works nice on your demo...take a look on mine: http://bit.ly/1d6UrnZ

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/p8hRR/4/

```
$(function() {
    var divs = [$('#section1'), $('#section2'), $('#section3')];

    fadeInFadeOut(divs);

    function fadeInFadeOut(divs) {
        var helper = function(methodToCall) {
            var i = 0;
            var processing = setInterval(function() {
                $(divs[i++])[methodToCall]("slow");
                if (i == divs.length) {
                    clearInterval(processing);
                    if (methodToCall !== "fadeOut") {
                        helper("fadeOut");
                    }
                }
            },250);
        };
        helper("fadeIn");
    }
});
```

Comment: No, I need to fadein one div after another...and not all at the same time...but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/t22sq/) showing what you want (I think). Html is what you showed.

JavaScript:

```
(function ($) {
    function fadeOut(div, sel) {
        var next;
        next = div.next(sel);
        next = next.length ? next : $(sel + ':first');
        return function () {
            div.fadeTo(2000, 0, fadeIn(next, sel));
        }
    }

    function fadeIn(div, sel) {
        return function () {
            div.fadeTo(2000, 1, fadeOut(div, sel));
        }
    }
    $.fn.fadeInNOut = function (sel) {
        $(this).find(sel + ':first').fadeTo(0, 1);
        fadeOut($(sel + ':first'), sel)();
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
$('body').fadeInNOut('div');
```

CSS (to see what's going on):

```
div {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
    opacity : 0;
    border : 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color : rgb(255,255,255);
    display : inline;
    font-size : 50px;
    float : left;
    height : 150px;
    line-height : 150px;
    margin : 10px;
    text-align : center;
    width : 200px;
}
#section1 {
    background : rgb(255,0,0);
}
#section2 {
    background : rgb(0,255,0);
}
#section3 {
    background : rgb(0,0,255);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help but I need to fadeIn/Out one after another..something like a slideshow! :D

Comment: Ah... I get it. Edited and updated the fiddle and answer. Wrapped the solution up in a little jQuery plugin in case you want to put a few of 'em on the page.